# htaccess restrict post access to specific url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have one site witch is encrypted and i cant make this inside code. So i know that we can redirect or throw 404 error via mod_rewrite.

Also my url is in cyrillic so in Chrome looks like

```
www.example.com/Нешто_два
```

but when i copy/paste it looks like

```
www.example.com/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%98%D1%82%D0%B5_%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82_%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%9A%D0%B5
```

i tried to use mod_rewrite to disable post request on that url, but still that url accept post requests. Tested by http tool.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /




    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/tiny_mce/.*$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(php|html?)$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^([^.]*)\.?(.*)$    index.php?q_url=$1 [QSA]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^Нешто_два$
        RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .htaccess file needs to have the URL in the escaped form, so rather than "Нешто_два", you should put the version that appears escaped "%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%98%D1%82%D0%B5_%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82_%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%9A%D0%B5"

That looks a bit long, so there might be some other stuff.  I tried just converting the string and came up with:

"\xD09D\xD0B5\xD188\xD182\xD0BE_\xD0B4\xD0B2\xD0B0"

The escaped versions can be put in the RewriteCond:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%98%D1%82%D0%B5_%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82_%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%9A%D0%B5$
```

Answer (score 0):

To restrict http post, you need to use the "Limit or LimitExcept directives inside VirtualHost or Directory block(if you don't put inside one of these it wont work!).
For example, the following will only allow http get in this site under

```
<Directory> 
 ........
<LimitExcept GET>
   Require valid-user
</LimitExcept>
```

If you using .htaccess file, just paste this portion without the Direcotry block

```
<LimitExcept GET>
   Require valid-user
</LimitExcept>
```